# How to draw arrows on curves in Metapost

Tags: metapost

I need to draw the following graphs using Metapost. How to draw the arrows on curves? Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add some example code to your question, e.g., code to draw the curves without arrows or code to draw arrows without curves. Also: is MetaPost strictly required? This can be done with packages like `tikz` or `pstricks` as well.

Comment: use `drawarrow` in combination with `cutbefore` and `cutafter`

Comment: Make your curves as named variables (type path), draw them, the use drawarrow + subpath to draw a shorter version of a given path on top if the original path, with an arrow at the end of the subpath. This data type path and subpath are one of the things I really miss in tikz.

Answer (score 7):

Metafun provides a macro `arrowheadonpath` to draw an arrow at any `time` on the path. Here is an example in ConTeXt which shows how the arrow looks like for all three arrow head variants provided in context:

```
\startMPpage[offset=1mm]
  save p; path p;

  p := (1cm, 1cm) {up} .. {down} (0,0);

  ahvariant := 0;
  draw p ;
  fill arrowheadonpath(p, 0.125);

  p := p shifted (1cm,0);

  ahvariant := 1;
  draw p ;
  fill arrowheadonpath(p, 0.125);

  p := p shifted (1cm,0);

  ahvariant := 2;
  draw p ;
  fill arrowheadonpath(p, 0.125);
\stopMPpage
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with plain Metapost as well.

```
prologues := 3; 
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

vardef open_arrowhead expr p =
  save q,e; path q; pair e;
  e = point length p of p;
  q = gobble(p shifted -e cutafter makepath(pencircle scaled 2ahlength))
    cuttings;
  (q rotated .5ahangle & reverse q rotated -.5ahangle)  shifted e
enddef;

vardef draw_open_arrow expr p = 
    draw p;
    draw open_arrowhead p;
enddef;

beginfig(1);
    path arc[];

    arc0 = 100 right .. 20 down {left} .. 100 left;

    arc1 = arc0 shifted 20 down rotated -10;
    arc2 = reverse arc0 shifted 20 down rotated 230;
    arc3 = reverse arc0 shifted 20 up reflectedabout(left, right) rotated 110;

    numeric t[], u[];
    (t1, t3) = arc1 intersectiontimes arc3;
    (u1, u2) = arc1 intersectiontimes arc2;
    (t2, u3) = arc2 intersectiontimes arc3;

    % def drawarrow = draw_open_arrow enddef;
    ahangle := 30;
    forsuffixes $=1,2,3:
        drawarrow subpath 1/2 ( 0,    t$)    of arc$;
        drawarrow subpath 1/2 (t$,    t$+u$) of arc$;
        drawarrow subpath 1/2 (t$+u$, u$+2)  of arc$;
        draw      subpath 1/2 (u$+2,  4)     of arc$;
    endfor

endfig;
end
```

Compile this program with `mpost` to get the following EPS figure:

[image]

Here I've used the default arrow heads with `ahangle` reduced from the default of 45 to 30, which makes them look a bit nicer in the middle of a line.

But if you prefer the open arrow heads in your sketch then uncomment the line

```
def drawarrow = draw_open_arrow enddef;
```

and make the arrow head angle a bit larger:

```
ahangle := 60;
```

These changes produce this figure:

[image]